# Microsoft related Retagging

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I've noticed some alternate tags that should be cleaned up. The first one listed for each of these should be correct (unless I don't know of some other naming convention).

```
windows-7
windows7

windows-vista
windowsvista
vista

windows-xp
windowsxp
windows xp
```

I've also noticed an `xbox360` tag - Should this be changed to `xbox-360`?

[Edited]

Actually, it looks like these tags are an issue on all sites (Server Fault <s>& Stack Overflow</s>)

Comment: Shoot, should I have just flagged a moderator on some relevant posts instead? I just noticed that on some other requests.

Comment: No, this is the right place, at least for now.

Comment: Windows-related retagging is discussed in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg/3820#3820

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with "windows" as the most broad tag and then "windows-[version]" as the specific ones ("windows-xp", "windows-vista", etc.)

If you come across things you think need retagged, you can flag and one of us will take a look at it, you can also email me directly (my address is listed on my SU profile page).

I think if we take care of these early, we won't need to worry about a big and potentially messy tag merge.

This is currently taken care of on Super User.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mention the plain windows tag, as it makes sense to keep :) - I'll email you about any future retags I notice.

Comment: Care to "own" SU if I clean up SO?

Comment: Sure why      not.